# How to transmit ASCII by WriteFile function

Tags: visual-c++, serial-port

I am writing following codes to transmit ASCII(62), ASCII(42),ASCII(62),ASCII(112) through serial port.

DWORD written;
WriteFile(serialHandle,">*>p",strlen(">*>p"),&written,NULL);

But right now I want to transmit ASCII(4).ASCII(0) also, but I don't know how to write them into char type.

If I write: WriteFile(serialHandle, 4,1, &written, NULL）； the VC++ system will give me an error message.

Would you please help me to re-write WriteFile function to meet my requirement?

Comment: WriteFile() doesn't care about the type, use `BYTE buf[] = { 62, 42, 62, 112 };`

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for your answer. I try to accept yours but I dont know how to do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to use " quotes with WriteFile. Seems like you should learn to use arrays.

```
char buf[2];
buf[0] = 4;
buf[1] = 0;
WriteFile(serialHandle, buf, 2, &written, NULL);
```